# Toggle Flashlight in Camera2 without Interrupting Preview

Tags: android, delay, preview, flashlight, camera2

Just started using the Camera2 framework because of the increased control it provides over the low-level functions of the camera. However, I am having some trouble turning the flashlight on and off quickly. With the old Camera API, I could toggle flash while supplying a preview by:

```
try
{
    android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters = c.getParameters();
    if (parameters.getFlashMode().equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF))
    {
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        Log.i("HeartBeatAlgorithm", "LightOn");
    }
    else if (parameters.getFlashMode().equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH))
    {
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        Log.i("HeartBeatAlgorithm", "LightOff");
    }
    c.setParameters(parameters);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    c.release();
    c = null;
}
```

And the flashlight would quickly turn on or off, without any noticeable interrupt. With Camera2, however, it seems as though flash mode is a property of the CaptureSession, meaning an entirely new CaptureSession needs to be created to change flash mode, i.e.:

```
try
{
    SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
    assert texture != null;

    texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
    Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
    mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

    if (mLightNowOn == true)
    {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    }
    else
    {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    }

    mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
    mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
    mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), mSessionStateCallback, null);
}
catch (CameraAccessException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As is mentioned in the developer docs, "Creating a session is an expensive operation and can take several hundred milliseconds, since it requires configuring the camera device's internal pipelines and allocating memory buffers for sending images to the desired targets." It definitely does, and there is a noticeable delay in my app when toggling flash mode.

I really need to be able to quickly toggle flash modes without interrupting the preview so much. Is there any way around this, or is it unavoidable due to the new API pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

It's not true that completely new capture session has to be created every time just to change flash mode. Instead, you can create repeating preview request on existing capture session and just setNewRepeating request every time such as this:

mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
...
mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
...
mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, captureCallBack, backgroundHandler);

You can repeat this sequence numerous times.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a bit hacky but Ivan's input worked for me...

If it isn't obvious the variable names are meant to look like the class/interface name.  You'll have to declare them in an outer scope.

```
captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
captureRequest = captureRequestBuilder.build();
cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest, null, backgroundHandler);

torchButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
torchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!lightOn) {
            try {
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                captureRequest = captureRequestBuilder.build();
                cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest, null, backgroundHandler);
                lightOn = true;
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {}
        }
        else if(lightOn) {
            try {
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                captureRequest = captureRequestBuilder.build();
                cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest, null, backgroundHandler);
                lightOn = false;
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {}
        }
    }
});
```

This way you'll start a preview with the torch off but that can be controlled by clicks of the button.